# variable in python

Tags: python

I get variables like these:

```
ocd[2].likelihood.range[1][0]=[-5219, -5191, 11.7];
ocd[2].likelihood.range[1][1]=[-5180, -5057, 56.5];
```

from an other program. I re-formate to:

```
range10=[-5219, -5191, 11.7];
range11=[-5180, -5057, 56.5];
```

for to use them in Python, but this is a lot of work, so my question is if it somehow is possible to use these variables with there original name in Python?

Comment: What exactly does "get variables from another program" mean? Why can't you use the original names?

Comment: do you get `ocd` list or just text?

Comment: ocd[2].likelihood.range[1][1]=[-5180, -5057, 56.5]; is one line in a long text file. I like to use [-5180, -5057, 56.5], and I hope to do so with "ocd[2].likelihood.range[1][1]" as a variable name in Python. If I can manage this I don't have to rename the variables before I use them i Python. As the number of variables is high it is a lot of work to rename them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

not sure what you are asking,, but i'll give it a try - in the "other" program's code do the following:

1. add this code before the first use of `range*` variables:

   ```
   class Likelihood():
       def __init__(self, x, y):
           self.range = [{} for i in range(x)] # without default values
           # if you need default values, use this code or numpy.zeros(shape=(x,y))
           #self.range = [[0 for j in range(y)] for i in range(x)]

   class MyDataType():
       def __init__(self, dimension_1, dimension_2):
           self.likelihood = Likelihood(dimension_1, dimension_2)

   ocd = [0, 1, MyDataType(100, 100)]

   # copy-paste your code here:
   ocd[2].likelihood.range[1][0]=[-5219, -5191, 11.7];
   ocd[2].likelihood.range[1][1]=[-5180, -5057, 56.5];

   print(ocd[2].likelihood.range[1][0])
   ```
2. replace all `range10` to `ocd[2].likelihood.range[1][0]`, e.g. in Notepad++ Regex replace:

   ```
   Find what:    range(\d)(\d)
   Replace with: ocd[2].likelihood.range[\1][\2]

   i.e. from code: print(range10)
   to code:        print(ocd[2].likelihood.range[1][0])
   ```

Comment: ClassNames should be CamelCase according to [PEP 8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

Comment: oh,, i forgot about lists being mutable and passed by handle, i fixed the code :)

Comment: Thanks a lot! Both versions worked, but only for ocd[2], the next data is ocd[3], etc (for instance: ocd[1121].likelihood.range[1][1]=[-5180, -5057, 56.5];) and for that i get "index out of range"

Comment: @PerPersson well, you can use `ocd = [MyDataType(10, 10) for i in range(9999)]` if you have enought memory to contain all data - but if you can't (or don't need to) stuff all data into memory, i would suggest parsing the output of previous program as text input - do you need to have access to all `ocd`, just 1 `ocd` or just 1 `range` at a time?

Comment: I used 999 and it worked fine! I do not think I come over 999. I am pleased with this solution. Otherwise I actually only need the variables one and one, I use Python to make figures of these data produced by an other program. At the moment I only want it to work. I promise that I will try to understand how it works later on. :-) Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in a pythonic way:

```
def range_function(row, column):
    return ocd[2].likelihood.range[row][column]

range_function(1, 0) == [-5219, -5191, 11.7]
```

Comment: I get the variables as long text-file list as output from an other program, I want to use the variables in Python.